# Highcharts export is navigating to demo page

Tags: highcharts

I am using HighCharts version 3.0.2. Have set up the Highcharts server locally for exporting the charts. When download as png/jpeg/pdf is selected from the top right corner of the chart , the Highcharts demo page is displayed.

Please let me know what could be the reason for this.

Note: Have set the Phatom js path in my app.properties file of highcharts export server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you're `exporting.url`ends without a trailing slash. The export-server will redirect the GET (without trailing slash) to the demo/welcome page

Instead of

```
exporting: {
    url: http://localhost/export
}
```

do this

```
exporting: {
    url: http://localhost/export/
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answering this. as you said trailing slash was missing.

Comment: gert vaartjes, I am aslo facing same issue. I dont have phantom JS in my solution. May i know a little bit about this exporting url?

Comment: What export server are you using then?

Comment: i am also facing same problem but i am using highchart in angularjs so how can fix it can you please help me